# Differenciate between different .CSS?

Tags: css, forms, button

My problem is that I have in my code the following .CSS for the structure "form":

```
form, .content {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; /*Not yet a member? Sign up*/
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #595959; /*Border register*/
    background: white;
    /*border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;*/
}
```

But I would like it to be different for the button I have (I don’t want a border with a width):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenfield" name="hiddenfield">
    <button class="button" name="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

I would want it to be with these characteristics:

```
.button {
    display: block;
    margin: auto; 
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background:#333333;
    color: white;
}
```

However, the .CSS of the  structure is also applied to the button. I would like to differentiate it, but I do not know how. I have tried in several ways, including:

```
form, .button {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Could you help me?
Thank you

The image of the button is here:

[image]

Comment: you want this `form .button` ?

Comment: I dont want the button to have the style of "form"

Comment: then you probably need to learn more about CSS selector and how they work ... because you will not have the style for form with that

Comment: But its working, I just dont want the button to have a border around it

Comment: `form .button` doesn't apply the styles of `form`, it's a CSS selector stating a `.button` inside a `form` (which has higher precedence than only `.button`, thus overwriting any `.button` styles defined previously). I'd at least try @TemaniAfif s suggestion. Or add `style="border:none"` to your button.

Comment: I tried changing the class to button2 but still doesnt work

Comment: With 'style="border:none"' still not works. The border is still there.

Comment: What border are you trying to remove...the one on the form when it has a button in it? Or a border on the button? Seems to work fine - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MBVJam

Comment: Im trying to remove the border of the button. But because it has the structure "form" in it, it appears the border of the "form, .content"

Comment: No, it doesn't. Unless you can demo the issue (ideally using Stack Snippets) we can't help. With the code you have the `button` does NOT have a border as I have demonstrated. The `form` has a border...which is why asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know weights of elements in css

- element (span, input, form...) = 1
- class (.my-class) = 10
- id (#my-id) = 100
- attribute (style="color:red") = 1000

`form, .button {` - style for form and button (separate)

`form .button {` - style for only button (weight 1 + 10 = 11)

`form button.button {` here you can override previous styles for element `.button` (weight 1 + 1 + 10 = 12)

```
form {
  border: none !important;
}
```

In your case not input has border, but form

Comment: I have tried with `style="border:none"` but the border is still there. It doesnt disapear.

Comment: @galep Very bad solution, but it can help you: `border: none !important;`

Comment: Okey I tried with `.button {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #e7e7e7; /* Grey */
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;    border: none !important;
}` but the border is still there

Comment: @galep but you wrote twice border. First time border: none, second: with important. You need to delete first.

Comment: Even if I delete it the border is still there... Im trying to remove the border of the button. But because it has the structure "form" in it, it appears the border of the "form, .content"

Comment: @galep May we look at screenshots?

Comment: Sure, I just added an  image description in the question. The button is light gray with a light gray.

Comment: I modified my post. Just add code to you style file (not modify anything)